# Need to make USB drive skip itself in boot order without changing bios

Tags: usb, boot, ini, bios

I know how to change boot order through bios settings, but I have a unique situation where doing it programatically would be better.  The company I work for sells and supports software remotely to thousands of non tech savvy customers.  We can't touch their hardware settings, we are only the software vendor.

Recently we rolled out a option for their PCI compliancy that requires a separate removable drive to store a private encryption key.  Customers that use this option have to leave a usb drive with a .dat file containing the RSA key at all times.  Currently this presents an issue when customers reboot.  Sometimes we can walk them through over the phone how to change their bios settings to skip the USB drive, but in many circumstances we cannot, because of the caller and the other end of the phone not being tech savvy enough to change bios settings, and different PC's having different BIOS setups.

So my question is, is there any kind of ini file I can create or boot record on the disk itself than can be added or changed to cause the system to see that there is no OS on the USB, keep going down the list of boot drives.  Instead, with no OS many PC's hang on Missing OS screen until we have customer remove drive reboot and plug back in after Windows starts to load.  All PC's are Windows, all XP or newer.

Comment: Instead of having the BIOS skip over the drive, it may be easier to make the drive bootable and configure it to **chainload**.  For example, the `grub` bootloader used by many Linux distributions has chainloading support, commonly used to have both a Linux partition and a Windows partition display in its bootmenu, but the menu is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about manipulating BIOS Setup data.  Unfortunately there is no industry-standard for computers to manipulate Setup fields, like the boot sequence, so any solution is likely to be vendor-specific.

An example:  Dell Inc. provides customers OpenManage Client Instrumentation (OMCI) that allows admins to remotely change settings, like boot sequence, via standard interfaces like CIM/WMI.  See this whitepaper:
http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/solutions/omci_info.pdf

Especially:

> OMCI is the Dell instrumentation package that enables OptiPlex™, Dell
>   Precision™, and Latitude™ systems to be managed remotely. OMCI
>   contains the underlying driver set that collects system  information
>   from a number of different sources on the client computer, including
>   the BIOS, CMOS,  System Management BIOS (SMBIOS), System Management
>   Interface (SMI), operating system, APIs, DLLs,  and registry settings.
>   OMCI exposes that information through the CIMOM interface of the WMI
>   stack. Thus, OMCI enables IT administrators to remotely collect asset
>   information, modify CMOS settings, ...

OMCI is specific to the Dell BIOS, so it won't work with other vendors' machines.  Other enterprise hardware vendors (e.g. HP, IBM) provide similar software.  If you can live with a vendor-specific solution, this may work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply, but no I am looking to do it programatically or by manipulating the boot sector on the USB drive itself. We have thousands of customers running hundreds of different types of computers, all with Windows, but I understand the BIOS approach.  I am looking for either a type of .ini file that can be loaded or a sector (low level type of formatting) that can be tested on a USB drive so that it still shows as removable storage in Windows but allows BIOS to skip over it (basically making it not bootable).  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask if your USB is actually non-bootable?
How did you format it?  FAT32, NTFS etc?

Why can't Windows bypass this usb when booting normally when (i assume) it is not bootable. Normally my system boots to Windows OS even if there is a non-bootable usb plugged in.

BTW have you tried keeping the DAT file on usb as hidden, read only, it's worth a try.

Comment: The USB drives are purchased by the end user, and we only need to put a DAT file (basically one half of a RSA key) that the program needs to access.  So these are just brand new flash drives usually out of the blister pack that show up under removable storage and we put a small file on them.  Some bios settings are set to look for the OS on USB before the HDD by default and since there is a file there it hangs and says "Missing OS".

Comment: I know how to fix the boot up sequence individually if I am in front of the computer, but we're talking thousands of different end users who have purchased their computers from many places, so lots of different bios(es) to deal with.  I was just wondering if there was some sort of file I could put, or sector of memory I could manipulate to cause the bios to skip it yet leave it as a "Removable Storage"